# MediaPlayer issues - audio file only plays back once

Tags: android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to implement a basic MediaPlayer in an app, and have the button change states depending on whether the clip is playing, playback is completed, or playback is manually interrupted (by pressing the same button).

With the code below, I get the following results:

1. On first load, the audio plays back fine.
2. If I press the ImageButton a second time during playback, the playback stops. When I press it again, the playback resumes from the timestamp in which it was stopped (I thought this was strange behaviour more typical of a "pause()".
3. Once the playback is completed, the button change works perfectly, however I can not replay the audio file a second time. When I press start, it starts playing back, then immediately transitions to playbackcompleted, without actually playing the audio.

I've been scouring through other posts / google / android documentation, but haven't found a solution as yet.

I have also tried so far:

1. setLooping(true); - this had no effect at all, other than the setOnCompletionListener never being reached. The audio did not replay at all.
2. In the onCompletion method, setting the seekTo() to several different values (0, 100), and using log messages including the "getCurrentPosition()" to confirm it was actually doing it, but even when this confirms that it's starting from position 0, or 100, the result is still the same (no audio is heard and completion occurs immediately).
3. In the onCompletion method, several combinations of calling "stop()", "prepareAsync()" or even prepare(). The results were the same, however on subsequent attempts (i.e. attempt 2, 3, etc) to playback, when the onCompletion method was called, I started getting various errors for calling stop() / prepare() methods in the incorrect state.

   ```
       final ImageButton pauseButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.playButton1);
       final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ch01_01);


       mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
               pauseButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_button);
           }

       });

       pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

               if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                   mediaPlayer.stop();
                   mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                   pauseButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_button);
               } else {
                   mediaPlayer.start();
                   pauseButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop_button);
               }
           }
       });
   ```

Any help would be appreciated!

P.S. I'm using all of this code in the onCreateView method for a Fragment in my application. Just in case anyone thinks that might be relevant.

Comment: I see two odd lines. First mediaPlayer.prepareAsync() after you stop player. prepareAsync() method triggers onPrepared listener after which you can start player. So you have to move prepareAsync line to "else" block, remove mediaPlayer.start() from else block to onPrepared method. Attach setOnPrepared listener to mediaPlayer. Please check this diagram: http://developer.android.com/images/mediaplayer_state_diagram.gif

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response!

The anomalies you noticed were just some things I was playing with to see if I get the same behaviour when I stop(); vs when it is in the Completed state.

I removed the stop(); and prepareAsync(); and replaced with a pause() instead. This pause function works fine, that isn't my issue currently. I just want it to be able to play again from the start after it's completed.

Once it's completed, it never plays again until I exit the activity and go back in.

When it's in PlaybackCompleted, I should be able to seekTo(0) and start again, but it doesn't work.

Comment: So, I've been running this on my Samsung Galaxy S2 (running Kitkat 4.4.4 Cyanogenmod).

I tried instead on my Google Nexus 7 (2013) running Lollipop and it works exactly how I wanted. There was a good few hours wasted *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this issue is simply my Samsung Galaxy S2, as the same code works perfectly as expected on my Nexus 7 (2013) running Lollipop 5.0.1.

The issue on the Galaxy S2 includes the following:

1. Once an MediaPlayer is in the PlaybackCompleted state, it will not play the same file a second time when play is pressed
2. Attempting to run Methods in the PlaybackCompleted state (which should be valid according to Android documentation) seem to do something (i.e. seekTo(0); will actually seek to 0, but the audio file will never play a second time.

Comment: Without thinking much more about it, in Developer options (Lollipop), you can find checked option "Use NuPlayer (instead of Awesome Player)". I would do additional test with emulated devices (different API's)